# certain photos upload by html form and php script are rotated horizontal from vertical

Tags: php, image, upload, compression

## as i'm also compressing the image before the upload (without compression images are not rotated)

this block must be reason

```
function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
      $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
      $image = imagecreatefromgif($source); 
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
      $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality); 
  }
```

this is the properties of the image :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK7D5.png)

I'm  facing this situation where only large images are rotated.

Comment: you should rotate the image to the right orientation before doing image compression. You may refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65260532/image-is-rotated-90-degree-when-displayed-image-captured-by-a-smartphone) -- please refer to the code from Mexx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.